# Parse HTML chunk with nbsp in MSXML

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, msxml, ixmldomdocument

I'm trying to load a chunk of HTML into MSXML's DOMDocument. The said chunk is valid XML with one excepton - it has `&nbsp;` entities. MSXML chokes on them, claims "Reference to undefined entity 'nbsp'.".

Can I make MSXML recognize it as valid somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: Just run a text replacement of "&nbsp;" to " " before parsing the document. Which should work, since there cannot be a verbatim &nbsp; in the text, which should not be replaced.

More standard solution: Declare a nbsp; entity in the xml, by inserting

```
<!DOCTYPE foobar [
   <!ENTITY nbsp " " >
]>
```

before the xml root node.

You can also use "0xA0" and &#x00A0; if you actually want a non-breaking space, instead of a normal space

Comment: Ended up with the first option. Oh well. I was hoping it was possible to load those files without modifying them - guess not.